# How to concatenate Pandas Dataframe columns dynamically?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe df (see program below) whose column names and number are not fixed.
However, there is a list ls which will have the list of columns of df that needs to be appended together.
I tried

```
df['combined'] = df[ls].apply(lambda x: '{}{}{}'.format(x[0], x[1], x[2]), axis=1)
```

but here I am assuming that the list ls has 3 elements which is hard coding and incorrect.What if the list has 10 elements.. I want to dynamically read the list and append the columns of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col_1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
        'col_2': [4, 5, 6, 7],
        'col_3': [14, 15, 16, 19],
        'col_4': [22, 23, 24, 25],
        'col_5': [30, 31, 32, 33],
    })

    ls = ['col_1','col_4', 'col_3']
    df['combined'] = df[ls].apply(lambda x: '{}{}'.format(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
    print(df)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         main()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `''.join` after converting the columns' data type to *str*:

```
df[ls].astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)

#0    02214
#1    12315
#2    22416
#3    32519
#dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cumulative sum over strings for this for more speed i.e

```
df[ls].astype(str).cumsum(1).iloc[:,-1].values
```

Output :

```
0    02214
1    12315
2    22416
3    32519
Name: combined, dtype: object
```

If you need to add space then first add `' '` then find sum i.e

```
n = (df[ls].astype(str)+ ' ').sum(1)
```

```
0    0 22 14 
1    1 23 15 
2    2 24 16 
3    3 25 19 
dtype: object
```

Timings :

```
ndf = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%%timeit
ndf[ls].astype(str).cumsum(1).iloc[:,-1].values
1 loop, best of 3: 538 ms per loop

%%timeit
ndf[ls].astype(str).apply(''.join, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.93 s per loop
```

Comment: In df[ls].astype(str).cumsum(1).iloc[:,-1].values , is there any way to add spaces in between the contents so that o/p looks like 
0 22 14
1 23 15
2 24 16
3 25 19

Comment: With two columns and 200,000 rows, I found the ```cumsum(1).iloc[:,-1].values``` idea to be twice as slow as the solution with ```apply ''.join()```. Maybe the method scales better as the number of columns increases.